# Printing different chars with different colors in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have String value which I take from firebase with the following format : [A7,B7,A#7,D7,A1]

When I print it in my application, it doesn't appear very clear. So I would like to hide the commas in the list or at least change their colors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to print the list without the commas ?

Comment: Yes or change the color of the commas

Answer (score 1):

You can use String manipulation to remove the commas:

```
myString.replaceAll(',',' ');
```